# Consumir Web Service,WCF dinamicamente

Tags: c#, wcf, webservice

Normalmente se agrega una Referencia web en el proyecto y listo lo consume desde ahí. Pero resulta que requiero hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

En mi `App.Config` voy a ir agregando los **WebService** (`.asmx`) y **WCF** (`.svc`) que requiero consumir, no se que métodos tienen, no se que parámetros piden. Lo que necesito es hacer algo similar a lo que hace `SoapUI`, donde "descarga" las definiciones y construye los `Resquest` a enviar, el usuario llena los parámetros y hace la petición.

De momento para la petición se me ocurre `HttpWebResquest`, pero para descargar la definición y armar los `Resquest` no. Alguien ha hecho, leído algo similar a lo que planeo hacer?

Saludos.

Comment: Como no sabes que metodos tiene y que parametros necesita????!!

Comment: @sioesi Si, lo que requiero hacer es montarle los Resquest a mi APP pero sin agregarle la referencia, osea sin recompilar el APP con la nueva referencia.. no se si me explico. Por eso especifique dinamicamente tipo SoapUI.

Answer (score 3):

La verdad es un poco complicado lo que solicitas. Para llegar a buen puerto necesitarías realizar lo siguiente:

1. Recuperar la descipción del servicio (wsdl) dada su uri.
2. Generar el código proxy dinámicamente desde la definición descargada.
3. Compilar el código y exponerlo en tu aplicación (usando Reflection)

Puedes revisar este artículo en el que se explica el proceso y posee código fuente para que vayas realizando tus pruebas. [Generate proxy code for a web service dynamically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dhrubach/2008/10/19/generate-proxy-code-for-a-web-service-dynamically/)